# Why is favour said to be “found” in the Bible?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, word-study

Why is favour said to be “found,” although people were not searching for it? Why does it not instead say, “favour found Noah” in Genesis 6:8?

> <sup>8</sup> But Noah found grace in the eyes of the LORD. <sup>NKJV, ©1982</sup>

Comment: Why should it say "favour found Noah"? That's not correct English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about English language; there is no hermeneutics involved.

Comment: The English verb ["to find favor"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/find-favor) has nothing to do with engaging in a search. In fact, it is a way of expressing approval that has not been ["curried"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/curry-favor). You have not tried to "find disfavor" in the eyes of Keelan, but it is pretty clear you have found it.

Comment: *Why is favour said to be “found,” although people were not searching for it ?* - You can find money lying down on the ground, without necessarily looking for them.

Answer (score 3):

Although in English the verb “find” is commonly used in the sense of “to discover or attain by search or effort,”<sup>1</sup>

[image: OED online, “find,” II., 9., a.]

it can also be used in the sense of “To meet with, come to have or experience, **obtain**, **receive**, **get** (chiefly, something desirable or needful).”<sup>2</sup>

[image: OED online, “find,” I., 3.]

Coincidentally, the Hebrew verb מָצָא (*matza*) conjugated in binyan Paʿal (Kal) can also be used in this latter sense. Gesenius wrote,<sup>3</sup>

[image: Gesenius, p. 499, מָצָא]

In summary, neither the English verb “find” nor the Hebrew verb מָצָא need imply that Noah was searching for favor when he “found” it.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> *Oxford English Dictionary* online, “find” (v.), II., a.
<sup>2</sup> *id.*, I., 3.
<sup>3</sup> Gesenius, p. [499](https://books.google.com/books?id=E80OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR499#v=onepage&q&f=false), מָצָא (*matza*), 1.

#### References

Gesenius, Heinrich Friedrich Wilhelm. [*Gesenius’s Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon to the Old Testament Scriptures.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=E80OAAAAQAAJ) Trans. Tregelles, Samuel Prideaux. London: Bagster, 1860.

*Oxford English Dictionary* online. (https://www.oed.com)